# Ruby print current visibility

Tags: ruby, scope, metaprogramming, visibility

So, with all the metaprogramming stuff in ruby (using 1.9.3), I guess there is a method which returns the current visibility.
Lets assume it is called `visibility`.

```
class Foo
  puts visibility
  # => "public"

  private
  puts visibility
  # => "private"
end
```

So, whats `visibility` - how can I get the current visibility the ruby interpreter uses when he finds new methods definitions?

Comment: Looks like the Rubinius guys had to implement something like this: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/35dbaf5efa8c3b0babf2b2ee656769cf8438b54f/kernel/common/variable_scope.rb#L141

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't a ready to use method. You could implement one, however, with something along the lines of (untested)

```
class Class
  def visibility
    define_method(:__visibility_discovery__) { }
    visibility =
      if protected_method_defined? :__visibility_discovery__
        "protected"
      elsif private_method_defined? :__visibility_discovery__
        "private"
      else
        "public"
      end
    remove_method :__visibility_discovery__
  end
end
```

Comment: This puts "public" twice. I guess define_method is always public.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you have three different levels of visibility for instance methods.

Methods default to `public`, which is what you are probably used to. You always have access to this method if you have access to the object.

`private` and `protected` are similar. They can only be accessed by the class and subclasses. The difference is that `public` methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver. What that means is you cannot call another method's `private` function from another instance of the same class, while `protected` can.

So if you need methods to be available outside of your class, stick to the default visibility of `public`. If your method needs to be accessed by any instance of that class, such as some custom comparison logic, use `protected`. And if your method is anything that should not be visible outside an instance of that class, use `private`.

To actually answer your question, `visbility` is a method that returns the current state of visibility - whether it is `public`, `private`, or `protected`.

Comment: I know all that. Sorry, you misunderstood my question, I have updated it a bit. I want to know, what the ruby interpreter thinks is the current visibility. So, when the interpreter encounters a new method: which visibility will it have?